# how can I load a tableplot, put random colors, and the legends automaticaly using a foreach?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, random

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scaled x ticks={real:1e3},xtick scale label code/.code={$\cdot 10^3$},
axis lines=left,
%xticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\lambda$}, pone lambda al lado del tikz
%xticklabel style={rotate=45,anchor=east},%rota los tixks
%/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={},%cambia la separacion de miles
%title=Pupila 1,
xlabel={$\frac{1}{F}$},
ylabel={$y$},
%ymin=0, ymax=3,
minor y tick num=1,
%enlargelimits=true
enlarge x limits=upper,
enlarge y limits=upper,
%cycle list name=exotic,
%patch,%punteadas
%fill=orange!75
%fill=-red!75!green
%stack plots=y,
%stack dir=minus,
%cycle list name=list3
%legend entries={$\sigma=0.0 5$,$\sigma=0.1$,$\sigma=0.25$,$\sigma=0.5$,$\sigma=1$,$\sigma=2.5$,$\sigma=5$,$\sigma=10$,$\sigma=25$},
legend cell align=left,
legend pos=outer north east]
%\addplot[blue] table {Libro1.txt};
\foreach\c in {0,0.005,0.015625,0.03125,0.0625,0.125,0.25,0.5,1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200,500,1000,2000,4000} {
\addplot[red,very thick] table [col sep=tab,trim cells=true,y=\c]{myFile.txt};
}
%\addplot[Chartreuse3,very thick] table [col sep=tab,trim cells=true,y=5] {myFile.txt} ;
%\addplot[DarkGoldenrod2,very thick] table [col sep=tab,trim cells=true,y=4000] {myFile.txt};
%\addplot[IndianRed1,very thick] table [col sep=tab,trim cells=true,y=c11] {myFile.txt};
%\addplot[MediumPurple3,very thick] table [col sep=tab,trim cells=true,y=c11] {myFile.txt};
%\addplot[magenta,very thick] table [col sep=tab,trim cells=true,y=c13] {myFile.txt};
%\addplot[Snow4,very thick] table [col sep=tab,trim cells=true,y=c15] {myFile.txt};
%\addplot[ForestGreen,very thick] table [col sep=tab,trim cells=true,y=c17] {myFile.txt};
%\addplot[black,very thick] table [col sep=tab,trim cells=true,y=c19] {myFile.txt};
    %\draw[red,ultra thick,densely dashed] (axis cs:6,0) -- (axis cs:6,1);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I have edited your question so that the code is highlighted and easier to read -- use the `{}` symbols to do this. Rather than asking the question in your title it is better to give more details and to explain what is wrong with your code and what you want to do. It is also helpful if you post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that compiles and does not contain any unnecessary code. This makes it easier for people to help you - and more likely that they will!